# JPQL Query gives exception when trying to add condition after order by

Tags: java, mysql, jpql

I am trying to execute a MySql query in JPQL.
Here is my MySql Query

```
select * from test.employee order by DEG != 'm2',DEG;
```

where `test` is schema name, `employee` is table name and `DEG` contains strings.
I wrote this in JPQL and got exception.

```
EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DBConnectionPU");
EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT em FROM Employee em ORDER BY em.deg != 'm2', em.deg");
List<Employee> list = q.getResultList();
```

**Exception :**

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT em FROM Employee em ORDER BY em.deg != 'm2', em.deg]. 

[36, 50] The order by item is not a valid expression.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
        at dbconnection.DBConnection.main(DBConnection.java:39)
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
    Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT em FROM Employee em ORDER BY em.deg != 'm2', em.deg]. 
    [36, 50] The order by item is not a valid expression.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
        ... 1 more
```

I tried this using criteria query and it works fine. Whats wrong with it in straight JPQL query? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `em.deg != 'm2'` to `case when`:

```
SELECT em 
FROM Employee em 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN em.deg != 'm2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, em.deg
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works !! Anything about reason behind it ?

Comment: @FahimFerojeAlJami Emm, Sorry for that, I've ever encountered this issue and `case when`  help me fix it, not research the reason for it.